# Serializing child classes with csvHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'd like to include values from a child class in my CSV output. The child class contains several Boolean values that indicate available actions.

```cs
public class AllowedActions {
    public bool CanCheckIn { get; set; }
    public bool CanCheckOut { get; set; }
}

public class ContentItem {
    public AllowedActions Actions { get; set; }
    public Guid? ContentTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

Can I create a class map that includes both the ContentItem properties, and the values of the AllowedAction class? Adding them to the map is causing a "Property 'Boolean CanCheckIn' is not defined for type 'XYZ.ContentItem'" error.

This doesn't work:

```cs
        Map(m => m.Actions.CanCheckIn);
        Map(m => m.Actions.CanCheckOut);
```

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out. In order to correctly map the members of the child class, I need to use `References` rather than `Map`, and provide a separate map object, like so:

```
        References<AllowedActionsClassMap>(m => m.Actions);

...

public sealed class AllowedActionsClassMap: CsvClassMap<AllowedActions>
{
    public AllowedActionsClassMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.CanCheckIn);
        Map(m => m.CanCheckOut);
    }
}
```

More information here: [CsvHelper Mapping](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#mapping)